# react-highcharts Y-axis categories catch event click in react way

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using react-highcharts and I'm trying to find a way to trigger an event when one of the Y-axis categories is being clicked. I'm using xrange graph.I want to get the offset of the value that was clicked. For example, if i have:

```
CatA

Catb

CatC
```

If I will click on CatB I will get 1.

I found a jquery solution, which give me the value itself. Its not a problem to get all the elements and iterate over them and found the offset myself. The solution of jquery:

```
$("#container .highcharts-yaxis-labels text").click(function() {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
```

I'm looking for react/react-highcarts solution for that.

**Update**

Thanks Kamil Kulig! Im getting trouble with the library. I import the library as

`import HighchartsCustomEvents from 'highcharts-custom-events';`

And nothing happned, also i added this code at componentWillMount function:

```
template.yAxis.events.click = function () {
            alert(1);
        };
```

I saw the docs and I didnt find any offset function, which means that sould I use jquery anyway? or do u have any idea?

Comment: You can perform operations either on axis' labels (`yAxis.labels.events`) or axis' title (`yAxis.title.events`). `yAxis.events` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts offers  **the custom events module** that is able to handle the actions that you require.

**Module reference on npm:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-custom-events

**Module reference on Highcharts website:** https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events

Sample code:

```
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                   // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting lost to combine it with react-highcharts module and es6, can you help?

Comment: I can help with the official wrapper for Highcharts (You're using a non official version). This doc explains how to import an extra module to Highcharts in React (by the example of Highmaps module): (https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

Comment: Wow alot ofrreact-highcharts... I will check that right away. Any idea for getting the offset?